How can I promote an org-mode headline around while preserving all other parent-child relationships?
Suppose I have an Org mode outline that looks like this:
* A
** A1
** A2
** B
** A3
** A4

I would like to promote headline B to a sibling of A. I can do this with M-<right> but then A3 and A4 will become children of B, as such:
* A
** A1
** A2
* B
** A3
** A4

I want to promote B while keeping every other headline under the same parent (i.e., all headlines starting with A should remain as children of A), so that I end up with:
* A
** A1
** A2
** A3
** A4
* B

I know I can do this by pressing M-<down> until B is the last child of A and then promoting it, but it would be nice if there was a single function for this. However, I haven't been able to find one. Does such a function exist? If not, is there a simple way to implement one?

You can probably write a function for the specific situation you describe, but it's going to be more effort than it's worth. I would fold  the headlines with S-TAB until I can see B in folded state (S-TAB twice) and then cut-and-paste: go to the beginning of B, press C-k C-k to cut the whole "line" (that gets the folded section as well), go to after A4, perhaps add a line with RET if needed, yank the B section by pressing C-y, and then promote it with `M-. That's an extension of how you move stuff from one place to another in Emacs, so it feels natural to me.

@NickD The solution using cutting and yanking would probably be to use org-cut-special and org-paste-special, and that's an option, but it's not ideal since I have to manually tell Emacs where to paste it.
